# Several problems after system restore

Tags: windows-8, performance, microsoft-office, system-restore

I had a problem with a program that I thought I'd be able to solve by doing a system restore.
The side effects however were too severe and made me undo the system restore. After the undo, the problems weren't solved at all...

My computer boots as fast as it did before, but almost none of my startup programs still start up. (in the task manager under the tab where the startup items are, they're still listed and active)

If I shut down or restart, my system takes about 3-5 minutes to do so (it stays in the windows 8 shutdown screen)

Programs take quite a while longer to boot up (where Word booted up in about 3-4 seconds, it now takes about 20 seconds, the same is true for Powerpoint and Visual Studio).

The last problem (that I currently know of) is that Outlook 2013 stays stuck at the splash screen and says 'loading profile'. I can't get it to open at all, even in Safe mode it won't budge...

What can possibly cause this kind of behaviour? I already scanned for registry problems with CCleaner and for malware with Malwarebytes.

edit: More problems found, if I try to go to the Windows Update screen, explorer hangs, and when I try to run things like DISM or sysscan in an elevated cmd, it doens't even start to do something...

Comment: I'm in the middle of my exams, so this is quite problematic.

Answer (score 0):

System protection is a feature that regularly creates and saves information about your computer's system files, programs, drivers, and registry settings. When you system restore, it takes you back to those original settings. Doing a system restore will only help if somehow those things get messed up/corrupted. To me it sounds like you have a hard disk problem. Try doing a disk error check. Your file system may have errors. Here is a complete guide on how to run the diagnostics/repair tools.
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disk-error-checking-windows-8
Good luck.

Comment: I tried restoring the disk. Some interesting things happened. my explorer crashed when trying to rightclick my hdd (an ssd if it matters), but i could rightclick it in the navigationbar from another dir. It found no errors on the HDD. However, when I did the exact same thing in safe mode, it didn't even load and told me there were errors and I had to close the dialog and fix them. It didn't tell me how though, and restarting like the tutorial said made no difference either. The chkdisk /f command didn't find any errors at all I'm afraid.

Comment: After that I did a check on the performance of my ssd with the software of the manufacturer (Samsung). Almost every single stat had decreased quite a bit. Random read went from 95732 to 42988, Sequential read went from 514 to 247, and sequential write went from 2453 to  269!! Random Write didn't increase all that much. The first test was from august 2014. I use my pc daily, but I don't think these are normal stats. I should mention though that I wrote 2.38 TB total up until now (according to samsung magician) and there's 99GB of free space left (465GB total).

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody would encounter a problem like this in the future..
I came to the conclusion that it was best just to renew my Windows installation.  No commands I found on the internet or checks found anything unusual. The only error reports that were generated were the ones about my sound driver.

After the semi-fresh installation, everything seems to work just fine.